# Study the sequence $x_n=\sqrt[n]{2^{n\sin 1}+2^{n\sin 2}+\cdots+2^{n\sin n}}$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, trigonometric-series

I am given the sequence:
$$
x_n=\sqrt[n]{2^{n\sin 1}+2^{n\sin 2}+\cdots+2^{n\sin n}}
$$
Where $n \ge 2$. I have to describe the sequence $(x_n)_{n \ge 2}$, where I am given the following options (I have to choose one):

**A.** convergent

**B.** bounded and divergent

**C.** unbounded and divergent

**D.** has negative terms

**E.** has infinite limit

What I tried was to use something like:

$$y_n = \ln x_n$$

$$y_n = \dfrac{\ln(2^{n \sin 1} + 2^{n \sin 2} + 2^{n \sin 3} + ... + 2^{n \sin n})}{n}$$

But I got stuck here and I can't find the limit. I should probably use a different approach, but I can't think of any. I can't continue what I've started either.

How should I approach this?

**By the way**, is choice **B** just something to trick me, or is it an actual possibility? Can a sequence be bounded **and** divergent? That doesn't seem right...

Comment: $1,-1,1-,1,\dots$ is bounded and divergent.

Comment: Note that $$x_n=\begin{cases}1&n\text{ is even}\\0&n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$ is bounded and divergent.

Comment: For b we can also read "bounded and not convergent" if with divergent you are thinking to the case $\pm \infty$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let
$$
a_n=\max\{\sin k: k=1,\ldots,n\}.
$$
Then $\{a_n\}$ is increasing and $a_n\le 1$, for all $n\in\mathbb N$, and hence convergent to some positive $a\le 1$. (In fact, it converges to 1.)

Then
$$
2^{na_n}\le 2^{n\sin 1}+2^{n\sin 2}+\cdots+2^{n\sin n}\le n\cdot 2^{na_n}
$$
and hence
$$
2^{a_n}= \sqrt[n]{2^{na_n}}\le \sqrt[n]{2^{n\sin 1}+2^{n\sin 2}+\cdots+2^{n\sin n}}\le 2^{a_n}\sqrt[n]{n}
$$
But $\,\,2^{a_n}\to 2^a$ and $\,\,\sqrt[n]{n}2^{a_n}\to 2^a$, and hence
$$
\sqrt[n]{2^{na_n}}\le \sqrt[n]{2^{n\sin 1}+2^{n\sin 2}+\cdots+2^{n\sin n}} \to 2^a.
$$
Thus **A** is the correct answer.

Note. In fact $a=1$, and thus 
$$
\sqrt[n]{2^{n\sin 1}+2^{n\sin 2}+\cdots+2^{n\sin n}}\to 2.
$$
This is due to [Weyl's Equidistribution Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence#Weyl's_criterion).

Comment: I have some questions, if you don't mind. Firstly, you said that the sequence $a_n$ is increasing and $\le 1$. Is it increasing because of the fact that it is a max function? So we always take the biggest value possible, therefore making the sequence increasing? And is it always $\le 1$ because $-1 \le \sin x \le 1$ and because we always take the max of the sine function, $a_n$ would eventually converge to $1$?  Lastly, what really confused me is how you got that first inequality? I understand that you needed it to apply the Squeeze Theorem and to find the limit, but how did you arrive at it?

Comment: $a_n$ is one of the values of $\sin{k}$ for $k=1,2,\dots,n$.  So $2^{na_n}$ is one of the terms in $2^{n\sin 1}+2^{n\sin 2}+\cdots+2^{n\sin n}$ and the remaining terms are positive.  This gives the first inequality.

Comment: Why does $a_n$ satisfy the criterion: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{2\pi i\cdot ma_n}=0$$For all $m\in\Bbb Z$?

Answer (score 2):

**not a solution**

Here is $n=2$ to $n=1000$.

[image: graph]

Visual impression: converges to $2$, but not monotonically.

Comment: We can see it's not monotonic with smaller numbers too: $x_5=2.127$ decreases to $x_6=2.072$ then increases to $x_7=2.08$.

Answer (score 1):

As  @Jam mentioned in comments and GEdgar in his answer, it is not monotonic at all as shown in the table for the very first values of $n$ (put them on a scatter plot)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 1 & 1.79188 \\
 2 & 2.59580 \\
 3 & 2.39393 \\
 4 & 2.22146 \\
 5 & 2.12745 \\
 6 & 2.07215 \\
 7 & 2.07967 \\
 8 & 2.19713 \\
 9 & 2.16297 \\
 10 & 2.13347
\end{array}
\right)$$
To extend GEdgar plot, consider $n=10^k$ and the values are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & x_{10^k} \\
 1 & 2.133472777 \\
 2 & 2.030634143 \\
 3 & 2.005381446 \\
 4 & 2.000775098 \\
 5 & 2.000100408 \\
 6 & 2.000012379
\end{array}
\right)$$

From these numbers, it seems that, more or less,
$$\log(x_n-2)\sim 0.567936 -1.96092\, k \qquad (R^2=0.998712)$$