# Convergence of a sequence involving exponential and sinus functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Study the convergence of the sequence
> $$
> a_{n}=\sqrt[n]{2^{n\sin1}+2^{n\sin2}+\cdots+2^{n\sin n}},
> $$ for all $n\geq2$.

I do not know how to start the study of the sequence under consideration. It looks strange to me, because it seems to be a double sequence depending on $n$ and the counter for the sum under the radical sign.

Which would be a good attempt to start?

Comment: Empirically, it appears that our task is to show it converges to $2$.

Comment: Since $\sin\lt 1$ and $\sqrt[n]{n}\to1$, this in fact reduces to showing that $\sum_{k=1}^n2^{n\sin k}$ has a lower bound which tends towards $2^n$; more empirical observation shows that for all $n\gt2$, $a_n\ge2$, so the goal is more concrete: if someone can show that $\sum_{k=1}^n2^{n\sin k}\ge2^n,\,\forall n\gt2$ then we are done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Study the sequence $x_n=\sqrt[n]{2^{n\sin 1}+2^{n\sin 2}+\cdots+2^{n\sin n}}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3457698/study-the-sequence-x-n-sqrtn2n-sin-12n-sin-2-cdots2n-sin-n)